# Subject.pipe(last()) vs. ReplaySubject(1)?

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

Is using a `Subject` with the `last()` operator the same as using ReplaySubject(1) from the point of view of the observer?

In other words in this case:

```
let s1 = new Subject<any>().pipe(last());
let s2 = new ReplaySubject<any>(1)();
```

So in this case if source of the sequence for both `s1` and `s2` is the same, then a subscriber of `s1` and `s2` will see the same value sequence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, they do not do the same thing.

The purpose of last is to block an observable from emitting anything until the observable completes, at which point it immediately emits whatever the last value was. Anyone who wants to see that last value must subscribe before it occurs.

The purpose of ReplaySubject is to be able to subscribe late. With ReplaySubject(1), if someone subscribes to the observable after it has already been emitting things for a while, they'll immediately get a replay of the last 1 thing that was emitted.

Example 1:

```
let subject = new Subject();
let s1 = subject.pipe(last());
s1.subscribe(val => console.log('first subscription', val));
subject.next(1);
subject.next(2);
subject.next(3);
subject.complete();
s1.subscribe(val => console.log('second subscription', val));
```

In the above example, you will see it log out 'first subscription 3', and nothing else.

Example 2:

```
let s2 = new ReplaySubject(1);
s2.subscribe(val => console.log('first subscription', val));
s2.next(1);
s2.next(2);
s2.next(3);
s2.complete();
s2.subscribe(val => console.log('second subscription', val));
```

In example 2, you will see it log out 'first subscription 1', 'first subscription 2', 'first subscription 3' 'second subscription 3'

Comment: Ah - Got it!  So last() only works after the Subject completes.  That was very helpful - thank you.

Answer (score 2):

To add to this answer: sometimes you run into issues with replaySubjects: when you do a pipe on it, it will return an Observable instead of an ReplaySubject.

So, to have your observables always return the last value you can use the shareReplay operator.

the usecase for ReplaySubjects and shareReplay is to notify subscribers who subscribe late about the previous values. Last() does not provide this

```
let subject = new Subject();
let s1 = subject.pipe(shareReplay(1));
```